# Import 1GB database with phpmyadmin created with phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup a development server at home to perform modifications on a phpbb installation, using phpmyadmin I create a backup and download then Running Uniserver Zero XI 11.7.3 and phpmyadmin I try to restore, I have worked past all typical time out issues and adjusted the phpini file, the problem I have is during the import it still times out ask me to reload the same file so it can continue after loading the same file 15 times it still never completes.

I tried exporting just the "users" table and then importing the "users" table the file is only like 78 meg and still having the same problem it never completes importing the file ask me to select the same file so it can continue to load after 10 times I stop it acts like its never going to complete.

I tried using MySQLDumper-Version: 1.24.4 to back up on the host then restore here and it works but on the host machine their is 77 tables and on the home machine it only has 55 tables, tried this several times and sometimes its only 53 or 54 tables.

Exporting and importing databases over 1 GIG is not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For a database over 1GB, I would recommend restoring a raw dump via command line instead of using phpMyAdmin, which can be a bit unreliable with large backups/restores.

Answer (score 0):

This feature can help you, in case there are uploads limits at the PHP level: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=upload#cfg_UploadDir

Answer (score 0):

To import databases larger than 80 mb or 100 mb you must do it by command console, for this:

Where user and password are the ones you use to access phpmyadmin

1: `mysql --user = root --password = adm`

2: `use dababasename;`

Where source is the directory where the sql file you want to import.

3: `source C: /Users/user1/Desktop/BBDD/database.sql`